# error: xxx cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: kotlin, dagger

I get the following build error in Kotlin:

> error: LoadingRecyclerViewItemAdapter cannot be provided
>   without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.

This is the class:

```
@PerActivity
class SelectAssetsView @Inject constructor(activity: Activity,
                                           private val adapter: LoadingRecyclerViewItemAdapter<Story>) : SelectAssetsContract.View, LoadingAdapterListener { }
```

and this is the module that Dagger uses:

```
@Provides
@PerActivity
fun providesSelectAssetsView(selectAssetsView: SelectAssetsView): SelectAssetsContract.View = selectAssetsView
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Recently I've had issues with kotlin and dagger when it comes to generics. Kotlin generates wildcards and dagger has problems picking this up. I'd try doing `LoadingRecyclerViewItemAdapter<@JvmSupressWildcards Story>` wherever you provide and require the adapter. This prevents kotlin from generating the generic type with a wildcard